# Can ArcGIS Server 10.1 GetFeatureInfo return the geometry?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, wms, geometry, getfeatureinfo

Using GeoServer I can make a WMS GetFeatureInfo request using the application/vnd.ogc.gml info_format and it returns the full GML of the feature, including the geometry.  This is really useful as I can then use this GML in the browser to highlight features.

Example GeoServer request:

> http:///geoserver/wms?LAYERS=&QUERY_LAYERS=&STYLES=&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&BBOX=&FEATURE_COUNT=10&HEIGHT=500&WIDTH=500&FORMAT=image/png&INFO_FORMAT=application/vnd.ogc.gml&SRS=EPSG:2157&X=500&Y=500

However when I run this against an ArcGIS Server 10.1 WMS the result doesn't include the geometry.  I know there are ways of customising an ArcGIS Server 10.1 GetFeatureInfo response (http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//005300000228000000), but I don't see any way of getting it to return the geometry.

I've tried the same with all the ArcGIS formats included in the GetCapabilities, but none of them return the geometry coordinates, they just give the geometry type.  E.g. the GeoJSON gives "GEOMETRY": "Polygon"

Is it possible to get ArcGIS Server 10.1 GetFeatureInfo to return the geometry coordinates?

Answer (score 2):

Any customisations of the GetFeatureInfo query are based on the INFO_FORMAT of `application/vnd.esri.wms_raw_xml` which returns XML.

This XML has a shape property, but this simply returns the geometry type as a string.

`<esri_wms:Field><esri_wms:FieldName><![CDATA[Shape]]></esri_wms:FieldName><esri_wms:FieldValue><![CDATA[Polygon]]></esri_wms:FieldValue></esri_wms:Field>`

The docs describe GetFeatureInfo as a service to return only attributes:

> The GetFeatureInfo operation works in the same manner, and is designed
>   to return the attributes of features queried in a map in various
>   formats such as HTML, XML, and plain text.

http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#//01550000053p000000

So it appears to me as though this is not possible through the WMS Server.